# culture name ne-NP not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, culture

I have to host an application built in c#.net, Asp.net and backend as oracle. This application is already hosted in one of the server and its running smoothly. I have copied all the files and folder in another server with same configuration as that of the currently running server.

The version of IIS is 6.0 and the machine has windows server 2003 running on it. When i deploy the application i get the following error message while browsing. Could anyone please help me with this issue.

```
 Culture name 'ne-np' is not supported.
Parameter name: name
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Culture name 'ne-np' is not supported.
Parameter name: name

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Culture name 'ne-np' is not supported.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord..ctor(String cultureName, Boolean useUserOverride) +7481609
   System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(String name, Boolean useUserOverride) +213
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride) +45
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.CreateReadOnlyCultureInfo(String name) +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.set_Culture(String value) +194
   _Default.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +232
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +282


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

Answer (score 1):

declare the culture in aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="xxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxx" Culture="ne-NP" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following line in web.config, hence no need to specify in each page

```
<globalization uiCulture="ne" culture="ne-NP" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: I get the following message,
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: The <globalization> tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute.

Source Error:
Line 71:  <system.web>
Line 72:   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 73:  <globalization uiCulture="nep" culture="ne-NP" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
Line 74: 
Line 75:  </system.web>